Recommended configuration of OpenDKIM TrustedHosts
In the process of migrating my mail server to a new host. One of my struggles is OpenDKIM isn't signing outgoing mail (not internal). Currently my TrustedHosts file is as follows:
127.0.0.1
::1
localhost
*.example.com

(Where example.com is my mail domain.)
I'm sending mail from my IMAP client from my phone. If I add my phone's IP, the message signs properly.
A number of tutorials I've seen run this layout, and is what I've had configure until the migration. Am I really to wildcard all hosts? What's the recommended configuration?

You should not be signing messages based on the originating hosts but only for authenticated users. Your question revolves around a single configuration parameter and does not really tell how your Postfix is configured and how OpenDKIM is integrated to it.
All mail user agents (MUA) should send mail through a separate smtpd instance (smtps on port 465). This instance should require SASL authentication, and as it is implicit TLS for SMTP submission (RFC 8314, 3.3) it is also secured by TLS. In master.cf you could have, e.g.:
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_sasl_local_domain=$myhostname
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject

It might be a good idea to further restrict that your users should not be using email addresses of other users by adding, e.g., these parameters:
  -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch

Now, as all mail from this instance is authenticated, you can sign it regardless of the IP address. The following configuration is an example that adds the OpenDKIM milter assuming it is listening on localhost:8891, continues without signing in case the milter is temporarily unavailable, and tells the milter that it should work in the signing mode (ORIGINATING).
  -o smtpd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
  -o non_smtpd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
  -o milter_default_action=accept
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING

(For the inbound mail on the smtpd instance on port 25 you should have the milter_macro_daemon_name set to VERIFYING, instead.)

"You should not be signing messages based on the originating hosts but only for authenticated users." -- I require authentication. I misunderstood the purpose behind trusted hosts, assuming it was the server's IP, not the client, which was read.
"Your question revolves around a single configuration parameter and does not really tell how your Postfix is configured and how OpenDKIM is integrated to it." - If changing TrustedHosts didn't solve the problem, I would've posted config. (Plus, there's a lot and I hate posting my true config publicly, with redactions.)

"All mail user agents (MUA) should send mail through a separate smtpd instance" -- Mine's on 587. Brief search shows some suggesting 465, and some suggesting 587 (that 465 is out-dated).
"It might be a good idea to further restrict that your users should not be using email addresses of other users" -- Hadn't considered that, but probably because I'm the only user. I'm missing smtpd_sender_login_maps and have smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject.

Sorry, smtpd_sender_restrictions not smtpd_relay_restrictions. Looks like that one is just empty.

Yes, these are just examples, as no configuration was given. As you have everything else covered, the first sentence probably already gave you the answer, and the rest is a good reference for the others.

Please read the RFC 8314 I linked in my answer. Before 2018 there was somewhat a consensus that STARTTLS (on 587 for SMTP) would replace immediate TLS handshake (smtps on port 465). However, this was reconsidered and the current best practice is to use implicit TLS for submission. The main reason is that STARTTLS makes downgrade attacks easy.
